# Flatlist triggers event for list item on form subbmit

Tags: react-native

I have a FlatList component, with data based on FlatListData state. Thing is it executes method bound with each FlatList item on add/submit event.

my flat list:

```
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.FlatListData}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.actionOnRow(item)}>
            <Text style={styles.flatlist_li} key={item.key}>{item.data} {"\n"}
              <Text style={{ color: 'lightgrey', marginTop: 10 }}>{this.transformTSintoDate(item.time)}</Text> {"\n"}
              <Text onPress={this.deleteItem(item)}>DELETE</Text></Text>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        }
        }
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.RenderSeparator}
      />
```

method deleteItem bound with Text element:

```
deleteItem(item) {
    alert('delete')
    // if (!item) return;
    // else {   
    //   const FlatListDataRemovedItem = this.state.FlatListData.filter(item => item.key !== item);    
    //   this.setState({
    //     FlatListData: FlatListDataRemovedItem
    //   })
    // }    
  }
```

this method is executed on submit event:

```
populateMainObject = (item) => {
    this.dataArr.unshift({ key: this.state._fee, data: this.state._fee, time: new Date().getTime() });    
    this.setState({
      FlatListData: this.dataArr
    })

    return this.dataArr;
  };
```

This is the code responsible for submitting form:

```
      <TextInput style={styles.input_adjust}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter amount"
        ref={el => this._input = el}
        onChangeText={_fee => this.setState({ _fee })}
      />

      <Button style={{ fontSize: 16 }}
        onPress={this.populateMainObject}
        title={'Submit'}
      />
```

Have read to deal with such issue using  within renderItem(), no luck however.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: submitting the form function deleteItem although is not linked is being executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how you wrote means executing the function immediately:

```
<Text onPress={this.deleteItem(item)}>DELETE</Text></Text>
```

As soon as JS executer will get to the line above - it will execute the function

so, to avoid that you should define a function, that will be called as a handler of onPress event

Try next:

```
<Text onPress={() => this.deleteItem(item)}>DELETE</Text></Text>
```

Instead of calling the function **deleteItem** - you should pass the function to the field onPress

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
deleteItem = (item) => {
    alert('delete')
    // if (!item) return;
    // else {   
    //   const FlatListDataRemovedItem = this.state.FlatListData.filter(item => item.key !== item);    
    //   this.setState({
    //     FlatListData: FlatListDataRemovedItem
    //   })
    // }    
  }
```

Comment: Might be this work **onPress={() => this.deleteItem(item)}**

Comment: although you've responded first, credits go to @Alex Shtromberg as his message fixed my issue, thanks